# Is it possible the given inequality holds for any positive values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is there any possibility that for any positive values of $\alpha_i$ also ($\alpha_i \neq \alpha_j$), the below condition holds ?

$$
\frac{(\sum_i^k \alpha_i)^2}{\sum_i^k \alpha_i^2} < \frac{(\sum_i^l \alpha_i)^2}{\sum_i^l \alpha_i^2}
$$ when $l > k$ ?

Comment: For example, if $\alpha_i=1$ for all $i$, $\frac{k^2}k\le\frac{l^2}l$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Forgot to mention that not all $\alpha_i$ can be equal. I modified the question.

Comment: Then $\alpha_i = 2^i$ works.

Comment: @ClementC. seems like there are are lot of solutions. Is there a generic structure for the solutions of this inequality ?

Comment: Why can't we just assume $\sum_i^k \alpha_i$ to be a arithmetic series with common difference 1? Wouldn't any other values of $\alpha_i$ affect all the fractions equally?